# Label ranges and colors in Python plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following I'm trying to plot points with color and label that changes for every j. What I'm getting is different color and one label in the legend for every couple (i, j):

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

color_list = ["blue", "brown", "red", "black"]
g = itertools.cycle(color_list)

primes = (139,149,151,157,163,167)
for j in range(50, 300, 10):
    col = next(g)
    for k in (primes):
        for l in range(10000, 20000, 500):
            start = time.time()
            generator(j, k, l)
            end = time.time()
            plt.plot(l, end - start, linewidth = 2, marker='o', color=col)
```

**Edit:** Updated the code with my original problem as I couldn't figure out if the solution from Ernest + Arya can work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the second loop over `i` pretty useless?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for j in range (0, 2):
    x = np.arange(0,9,2)
    y = np.ones_like(x)*j + 0.5
    plt.plot(x,y, marker='o', label='$n = {j}$'.format(j=j))

plt.legend()    
plt.show()
```

[image]

Solution for updated question:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

color_list = ["blue", "brown", "red", "black"]
g = itertools.cycle(color_list)

for j in range (0, 2):
    col = next(g)
    x = np.arange(0,9,2)
    y = np.ones_like(x)*j + 0.5
    plt.plot(x,y, marker='o', color=col, label='$n = {j}$'.format(j=j))
plt.legend()  
plt.show()
```

[image]

Solution for second update; the idea is always the same: use as many calls to `plt.plot()` as you want to have different colors/legend entries.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

def generator(j,k,l):
    #some operation that takes a little time
    a = np.random.rand(k % 7, l-1000, j%13 )
    return a

color_list = ["blue", "brown", "red", "black"]

primes = (139,149,151,157,163,167)
for j in range(50, 300, 25):
    x = []; y = []
    for k in (primes):
        for l in range(10000, 20000, 1000):
            start = time.time()
            generator(j, k, l)
            end = time.time()
            x.append(l); y.append(end - start)
    plt.plot(x,y, ls="", marker='o', label='$n = {j}$'.format(j=j))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I agree, but it was just a simplified example for two or more nested loops, not necessarily with those points to plot.

Comment: Sure, but the same strategy applies to any number of plots. Simply don't use the inner `i` loop. (This also applies to the edited question.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the matplotlib [cycler](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/color_cycle_demo.html). Set up the list of colors you want to iterate over, then inside the `j`-loop, get a color with `my_cycle.next()`. Then pass that color into your call to `plt.plot`.

Comment: Is it similar to `itertools.cycle()`?

Comment: Yes—it relies on `itertools.cycle()` and adds some additional self-awareness, like its length.

Answer (score 1):

you can use sin or cos functions to control color choice and add a variable that changes only when j changes to control whether you plot a new label

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

last_j = -1
z = 5
for j in range (0, z):
    color = ((math.sin(j)+1)/2,(math.cos(j+1)+1)/2,(math.cos(j)+1)/2)
    for i in range (0, 10, 2):
        if j == last_j:
            plt.plot(i + 0.5, j + 0.5, c=color, linewidth = 2, marker='o')
        else:
            plt.plot(i + 0.5, j + 0.5, c=color, linewidth = 2, marker='o', 
                label='$n = {j}$'.format(j=j))
        last_j = j

ax = plt.gca()
legend = ax.legend(loc = 'center right', shadow=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]